# Whats ??= operator in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, operators

This is the new assignment operator I see in Flutter source code:

```
splashFactory ??= InkSplash.splashFactory;
textSelectionColor ??= isDark ? accentColor : primarySwatch[200];
```

what's the meaning of this assignment operator?

[example in Flutter source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/57a13c3e3bb94d1997815faf33aa2eb17690ee46/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart#L338)

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour

Comment: ?? is a null check operator. String name=person.name ?? 'John';

Answer (score 7, accepted):

??= is a new null-aware operators. Specifically ??= is null-aware assignment operator.

> ??
> if null operator. `expr1 ?? expr2` evaluates to `expr1` if not `null`, otherwise `expr2`.

> ??=
> null-aware assignment. `v ??= expr` causes `v` to be assigned
> `expr` only if `v` is `null`.

> ?.
> null-aware access. `x?.p` evaluates to `x.p` if `x` is not `null`, otherwise evaluates to `null`.

Answer (score 1):

**??** is a null check operator.

```
String name=person.name ?? 'John';
```

if person.name is null, then name is assigned a value of “John”.

**??=** simply means “If left-hand side is null, carry out assignment”. This will only assign a value if the variable is null.

```
splashFactory ??= InkSplash.splashFactory;
```

Answer (score 0):

The ?? double question mark operator means "if null" take the following expression.