# What means the operator "??" in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, operators, ternary

I've seen this code and need an explanation for "??".
I know ternary operators like "?" and then the true-condition and after ":" the false/else condition.
But what means the double "??" ?

Thanks in advance

````
      widget.secondaryImageTop ??
      (widget.height / 2) - (widget.secondaryImageHeight / 2); ```
````

Comment: Whyever did you toss the java tag in there? Removed it for you :)

Comment: [?? operator](http://blog.sethladd.com/2015/07/null-aware-operators-in-dart.html) check this out

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54031804/what-are-the-double-question-marks-in-dart#:~:text=answer%20was%20accepted%E2%80%A6-,The%20%3F%3F,operator%20means%20%22if%20null%22.&text=Another%20related%20operator%20is%20%3F%3F%3D,.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Whats ??= operator in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64642572/whats-operator-in-dart)

Comment: This is explained in [the Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#conditional-expressions).

Answer (score 13):

[List of all dart operators](https://www.w3adda.com/dart-tutorial/dart-operators)

it's the coalesce operator.

`a ?? b`

means: if a is not null, it resolves to `a`. if `a` is null, it resolves to `b`.

SQL and a few other languages have this operator.

Answer (score 5):

You example:

```
widget.secondaryImageTop ??
      (widget.height / 2) - (widget.secondaryImageHeight / 2);
```

This will use widget.secondaryImageTop unless it is null, in which case it will use (widget.height / 2) - (widget.secondaryImageHeight / 2).

Source and detail, including dartpad where you can try things out with pre-populated examples:
https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet

An example from that documentation, using the = sign as well.

> the ??= assignment operator, which assigns a value to a variable only
> if that variable is currently null:

```
int a; // The initial value of a is null.
a ??= 3;
print(a); // <-- Prints 3.

a ??= 5;
print(a); // <-- Still prints 3.
```

Answer (score 0):

It means => if exists and if not null...