# Flutter: what is ??=

Tags: flutter, dart

Basic question. Yes I know, just read the doc but by asking google, I didn't find the answer in less than 5 minutes so I think by adding this question, I will help all the following people to find the answer quickly (before GPT become the norm).

So:

`x ??= y`

What is it for ?

Comment: This answer from the above question covers it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64664404/2641242

Comment: `x ??= y` it's equivalent `if(x==null)x=y`

Comment: Check [What are the ?? double question marks in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54031804/10157127)

Comment: Arf, if I post this question, it's because the other isn't the same problem so I didn't find it.
And it is already marked as a duplicate !!!
If you delete mine you will just have more people not finding the SO post...
My post is talking of x =?? y not  x ?? y : z

Comment: Now actually I'm thinking, i might tag the wrong question. but the answer section solves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x ??= y` means assign `y` to `x` only if `x` is null.

Find more about [assignment-operators](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#assignment-operators)